# Rendering multiple webpages into a pdf using PhantomJS

Tags: html, pdf, phantomjs

I want to use phantomjs to render html pages into pdf. 
Here is my sample code.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://google.com', function() {
  page.render('google.pdf');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Is there a way I can take multiple webpages and render it into the same pdf using phantomjs?

Thanks!

Comment: No, or at least not easily. Use your favorite pdf tool to concatenate them afterwards.

Comment: I cant. I need it to be coded.

Comment: Then find a commandline tool that does this and call it either from PhantomJS or after the PhantomJS script has run.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this from inside phantom if you want, but it's a bit complex.

here is the psudocode you need to follow

1. for each webpage you want to render

   1. load the page
   2. add the value of `page.content` to a `pageHtmls` list
2. create a new `WebPage` object, and set `page.content=pageHtmls.join()` (you might have to scrub out the `<html>` and `<body>` tags though)
3. render the page as a PDF